# How to update peerDependencies of child projects/libraries when upgrading Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package.json, peer-dependencies

I just upgraded a project from Angular 12 to 13. The [ng update](https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-13.0) CLI updated the versions of packages in the `package.json` at the root of the project.

But the angular packages mentioned in `peerDependencies` inside `package.json` of individual libraries inside the `projects/` directory are still on Angular 12.

Is there a CLI available to update them automatically to coincide with the versions from the root `package.json` or do I need to go in each library and update its `package.json` manually?

Directory structure:

```
my-project/
|---- projects/
|     |---- my-library1/
|     |      |---- package.json (peerDependencies still on Angular 12)
|     |
|     |---- my-library2/
|           |---- package.json (peerDependencies still on Angular 12)
|
|---- package.json (All dependencies & devDependencies migrated to Angular 13)
```